# LISTEN on all channels in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq, postgresql-9.5

I'd like to forward all notifications from PostgreSQL into task queues in RabbitMQ named the same as the channel given in `NOTIFY channel`. Does PostgreSQL have something that would act like `LISTEN *`?

Inspecting the source for [Skeeter](https://github.com/SpiderOak/skeeter/blob/master/src/main.c) it seems that `PQnotifies` might be of interest. [PostgreSQL's documentation on libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-async.html) also mentions `PQconsumeInput` as a way to consume input from the server. From the documentation:

> PQconsumeInput normally returns 1 indicating "no error", but returns 0 if there was some kind of trouble (in which case PQerrorMessage can be consulted). Note that the result does not say whether any input data was actually collected. After calling PQconsumeInput, **the application can check PQisBusy and/or PQnotifies to see if their state has changed.**

Am I on the right path? Since I'm using .NET I'd prefer not writing any C, so any suggestions are welcome.

I've tried [pgsql-listen-exchange](https://github.com/aweber/pgsql-listen-exchange) but either I'm doing something wrong or the plugin doesn't work for RabbitMQ 3.6 (there's only a 3.5 release). I created an [issue](https://github.com/aweber/pgsql-listen-exchange/issues/19).

Specific to RabbitMQ: As an alternative to listening for everything from PostgreSQL, I guess I could create an exchange and have something poll that for queues and just create a listener for each queue. Will be looking into this as well.